# Complicated parallax effect element positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the problem, I'm using the Skrollr plugin to make a Parallax effect / animation site to present a product for one of my clients.

Now I am having a big problem with positioning, I'd need to position elements just outside the viewport, but they must be attached to a fixed wrapper, and animate to the center of the div.

I'd love to do this only in css to avoid too much js (Skrollr uses the css code ton animate anyways).

What I have tried is mearly positioning my elements with +200% or -200%, this works well on smaller screens, but on huge ones, we still see those elements. So this isn't a good solution.

I've tried to use the css3 values VH and VW, but to get them positioned in the center of the screen is a problem after, and it seems buggy between Firefox and Chrome.

Here is also my testings, this one is using %:

http://natcom.fr/commun/sites_construction/animation/old

And this is using VH and VW:

http://natcom.fr/commun/sites_construction/animation

I thank you all in advance for any help you could give.

Comment: Here is a gif explaining what I need :

http://i.imgur.com/MHP4ToJ.gif

Comment: Did you try the `left` property?, you could do left: -300px; where 300px is the width of your element.

Comment: Yes of course, on both examples left top right and bottom are used in different situations

Answer (score 0):

Here you go =), but one problem is when the inner-div gets the position absolute/relative it doesn't work anymore.
But i don't know your full html structure etc.

You could also take the object out of the inner-div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, html {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .outer-div {
                left: -200px;
                right: -200px;
                position: absolute;
            }

            .object {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background: #0000FF;
            }

            .move-object {
                transition-duration: 10s;
                margin-left: -100px;
                left: 50%;
            }

            .inner-div {
                width: 500px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 200px;
            }


        </style>
        <script>
            function moveit() {
                var element = document.getElementById('testobj');
                element.setAttribute('class', 'object move-object');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="moveit();">Click</button>
        <div class="outer-div">
            <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="object" id="testobj">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```